# Syntax highlighting only matches strings if the character before the opening quotation mark is a letter

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a syntax file. To highlight strings, I'm defining a region just like it says in the help file:

`syn region m2String start=/"/ skip=/\\"/ end=/"/`

and later I have:

`let b:current_syntax = "m2"
 hi def link m2String String`

However, this isn't behaving the way I want it to. After some experimenting, I figured out that vim is only highlighting strings if the character before the first quotation mark is a letter. Here's a screen shot:

[image: example of my wonky syntax highlighting]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? If it helps, I'm using vim version 7.4.1689 in the terminal. My terminal is xterm-256color.

Comment: You probably want to do something with `contained` and/or `contains` keywords in some `:syntax` command, but without seeing the full syntax with you're trying to modify it's a bit hard to say where exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit: the original author of this syntax file included the line
`syn match m2Keyword /\A\+/`. I guess this matched the first quotation mark before the string region did.